# My Bluetooth is gone on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, windows-insider

I have a Samsung laptop, model NP300E5L-KF1BR with Windows 10 Education on Windows Insider Preview, with Slow Ring. My build is 16299.15.

I also have a Bluetooth mouse from Microsoft and since this afternoon, my Bluetooth simply went missing and my mouse didn't worked anymore.

There isn't a option to turn Bluetooth on anymore, and Troubleshooting says that my laptop doesn't have Bluetooth (which is false).

On Device Manager, Bluetooth only shows if I check to show hidden itens.

[image: Device Manager screenshot]

How can I get Bluetooth back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I selected the Bluetooth device on Device Manager and removed it. Then I rebooted twice (on the first one Windows asked to reboot again) and it now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please open Services.msc and check if the service Bluetooth Support Service is started automatic.

Fail to start the service, run commands as below to scan and repair system files:

sfc /scannow

Comment: I solved it, but there is no such service on my Windows anyway, for some reason

Answer (score -1):

Just FYI i was having the same issue with the one i bought after windows 10 upgrade the BT disappeared and i couldn't get it back i tried installing drivers, system restore, everything i could think of. tonight i was tinkering with it and i opened my PC up removed the wireless card wiped off the connectors put it back in and my Bluetooth is working 100% hope any one out there searching sees this and it will help them fix their issue. obviously attempt at your own risk.